# Weird behaviour when using dsm

Tags: 7, debugging

I am using Drupal 7 on a CentOS 6.5 box. I am trying to debug some code which produces the following error:

> User error: ImageMagick error 1: convert: no decode delegate for this
>   image format  `/tmp/thesis-163.OBJ.xml' @ constitute.c/ReadImage/503.
>   convert: missing an image  filename`
>   jpg:/tmp/thesis-163.OBJ.PREVIEW.jpg' @
>   convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2800.  in _imagemagick_convert_exec()
>   (line 519 of
>   /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/imagemagick/imagemagick.module).

I can see that the problem is caused by the fact that ImageMagick is trying to make jpg out of a xml file. What the error is about, isn't really the issue. The issue is that, when I insert a dsm statement to check what is going and run the program again, the error goes away. If I comment out the dsm statement and run the program again the error returns. I have never seen this type of behaviour before and can't explain it.

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this behavior with a small snippet of code otherwise I would post it here.

Can someone explain why this is happening so that I can fix it?

Comment: do you test `dpm` instead of dsm and the error exists?

Comment: dsm maps to dsm, so should be: https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm/7

Comment: @tunic s reply below seems really interesting, using dd is a great tip, and another possible reason might be the session (ie dpm putting stuff into the session) ? but it would probably really help to see at least a part of the code :)

Comment: Sorry not an answer but you might have some luck using the `object_log` module which saves krumo to the database instead of printing to the screen. You can access it in the backend under Reports > Object Log

Comment: @leexonline That sounds very interesting. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing a Krumo side effect:

https://drupal.org/node/1855468

The problem is that PHP handles references to array elements in a risky way, see this article: [PHP: References To Array Elements Are Risky](http://float-middle.blogspot.de/2010/02/php-references-to-array-elements-are.html)

I haven't read the post deeply, and can't assure you have this problem, but you may try the workaround to see if it works: use [Krumo NG](https://drupal.org/project/krumong).

Another way is to use dd to dump your traces to a file, see functions documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7

Comment: Thanks for the useful links. I will give Krumo NG a try and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May want to try one of these or some combination of them. Sometimes dsm gives me weird behavior and I have to resort to one of these.

```
print '<pre>' . print_r($your_item) . '</pre>';

print '<pre>' . dsm($your_item) . '</pre>';

drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($your_item,true) . '</pre>');
```